# "Загляденье" пишется только через Ь или через И тоже?

Tags: орфография

В "грамоте" вариант через И тоже есть, но в примерах только через Ь. Так как же: один или два варианта?

Comment: Где именно "В грамоте"?

Comment: В статье на "загляден*е" (ссылка чуть-чуть не поместилась).

Comment: _Артём Луговой: ...но в примерах только через Ь._ === См. примеры: http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E7%E0%E3%EB%FF%E4%E5%ED%E8%E5

Comment: Спасибо, Слава, посмотрел!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба написания приемлемы, по-моему.  С мягким знаком это слово просто чаще используется.

Можно посмотреть употребление, например, [вот в этом справочнике](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Меня интересует, не ошибочное ли это употребление через И.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой : Не думаю.  Ошибкой можно было бы считать, если оно совпало бы с каким-то другим словом или частью речи, таким образом портя восприятие/звучание.  Толковый словарь Ефремовой содержит эту форму, так что можно не сомневаться.

Comment: Поверю тогда, спасибо.)

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта вполне корректны. Дело в том, что в русском языке написание -ние(-ание, -ение) или -нье(-анье,-енье) в суффиксах отглагольных существительных определяется или смысловом различием, или стилистической дифференциацией слов. Оставим смысловую сторону в стороне, перейдем к стилистике.
Слова книжные пишутся с суффиксом-ение, например: высказывание, достижение; слова разговорные с -нье, напр.: беганье, дерганье. отступление от этого положения , связанные с требованием ритма или рифмы, встречаются в стихах. Ср.: Я помню чудное мгновенье...

Розенталь Д.Э.

Что касается вашего варианта, то здесь, видимо, закрепилось два варианта. Потому что само слово разговорное.

Comment: Спасибо! Принял бы и этот ответ, да два сразу не примешь.))

Comment: Артем, да это и необязательно.